I want to remove alternate frames from video strip in blender using python
I write this code in blender to update the video strip so as to delete alternate frames from it and leave rest of the frames in video sequence editor but it removes first half of the strip instead of alternate frames. Please let me know where I am doing it wrong.
import bpy

# Set the name of your video strip
video_strip_name = "YourStripName"

# Get the video sequence editor
vse = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor

# Find the video strip by name
strip = vse.sequences.get(video_strip_name)

if strip:
    # Create a new list to store the frames to be removed
    frames_to_remove = []

# Iterate through the frames and identify alternate ones
    for frame in range(strip.frame_final_start, strip.frame_final_end + 1):
      if frame % 2 == 0:
        # Add the frame index to the list
        frames_to_remove.append(frame)

 # Remove the identified frames from the beginning
   for frame_index in frames_to_remove:
    strip.frame_final_start += 1
else:
  print(f"Video strip '{video_strip_name}' not found.")

  print("Alternate frames removed successfully from the beginning!")


Hello and welcome to ChatGPT... I mean BSE :) "I write this code" > I asked ChatGPT and it said that it was most likely GPT generated. It seems you want us to fix what it generated?

Yes you got it right as I do not know python. I just want to get this code fixed.

What are the "alternate frames"? From the code it is the even frames. Do you want to edit bpy.types.ImageSequence.elements?

@unwave he cant answer that due to having no python experience. just fix the code thats what he wants.

AFAIK There is no such thing as "remove frames from a strip" in Blender. You could cut the strip at each frame and remove odd ones. Which has the advantage of working with the audio strip, but I reckon to be wasteful and tedious ressource-wise. A simpler way would be to use ffmpeg to export your video as an image sequence and delete odd ones using python. But that's off topic here.

@Jatin Specify if your strip is the sequence of images ImageSequence. In other context the code will not work.  You would have to split the video into images or just use ffmpeg.

import bpy

# Set the name of your video strip
video_strip_name = "maserati red fron dof high.001"

# Get the video sequence editor
vse = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor

# Find the video strip by name
strip = vse.sequences.get(video_strip_name)


start = int(strip.frame_start)
duration = int(strip.frame_duration)
end = int(start + duration)

print("start", start)
print("end", end)
print("duration", duration)

counter = 0

for (cut) in range(start, end):
    
    if cut % 5 == 0:
        
        counter += 1
    
        print('cut', end-cut)
        
        new_strip = strip.split(frame=end-cut, split_method='HARD')
        
        if counter % 2 == 1 and new_strip != None:
            bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.remove(new_strip)
            
        if counter % 2 == 1 and new_strip == None:
            bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.remove(strip)
        

Note: you should be honest - not only here, that makes things easier. And i am pretty sure that's why nobody answered you - and that's why you did get 3 downvotes (until now). Nevertheless - i believe people can learn from mistakes - that's why i do answer.
result demo:
https://github.com/luckychris/blender_gifs/blob/main/delete%20partial%20strips%20demo.gif

Note2: once there was a great feature in SE: gif upload. This enriched this community a lot because you could show e.g. working examples or results. Unfortunately SE "killed" that by their latest "upgrade" which i think is more a downgrade. But that's just my personal opinion.

@Leander: i have no idea why you think you have to undelete my deleted post!?

I think the "downgrade" was done for good reason https://snipboard.io/bAdi2h.jpg You can still upload up to 2mb gif files.

@Chris Huh, I didn't undelete your post? I only rolled back the edit that obfuscated the actual post. By all means leave your post deleted.

sorry, i didn't make myself clear. You cannot undelete it - that's right. By why did you roll it back? i had reasons why i did make "points" there, or how you call it "obfuscate". It was deleted anyway, so just a few people could see it. So i don't get it... i would prefer if you don't change my deleted answers. thx for your understanding.

@HarryMcKenzie: nope, also smaller gifs won't upload here. You can also read here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398974/uploading-a-gif-doesnt-work-on-some-se-sites - so, no, i am not the only one with that problem....

Thanks you Chris. I was expecting the same output. Thanks Again

you are welcome

@Chris They broke it. Can still do that: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/316499/how-to-rotate-orientation-of-an-image-imported-as-plane/316522#comment549412_316499

@unwave: thx for the info!

With https://ezgif.com/ to reduce size (and quality) to 2 Mb can use in sequence: Resize (640p, ImageMagick + coalesce (undo optimizations)) -> Remove every 2nd frame -> Speed 50% -> Optimize Transparency (7) -> Color Reduction + dither (64) -> Lossy (128)

It is a heavy optimization and rather requires a more concise/split in parts footage material. It is the GIF format compression that is outdated. I would rather have a .mp4 upload that is limited to 2 Mb.
