How to rotate orientation of an image imported as plane?
Some solutions I have tried
this one How do I fix the size and rotation of my pictures? - proof https://www.loom.com/share/8381856b4a5f4e16be0f3fe3d7e0a7fa
this one How to Change Object's local Axis? - proof https://www.loom.com/share/c6d8bb51f4374943bcdaee4c4521bd89
I just want to change the image without rotating the frame of it.
The image file is correctly orientated in my file system, however when I open it through blender I can see it in the wrong orientation



Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos For me uploading gifs currently also does not work. This advice helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/399058/572705

Indeed, they have been experiencing issues during the transition phase. Thanks for the research, that will help users with the same issue.

Edit the UVs using the Constrain to Image Bounds option. After rotating scale it up so the constrain picks up.

